# What is the exact meaning of "call" resounding in the US media

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

After the election, I hear, to me, new usages of 'call'.

> AP called Arizona for Biden

> The results are too close to call.

In first look, I rendered it as 'announce' something. But I see this is tainted with a sense of prediction. What is the exact meaning of this 'call' here?

Comment: Didn't we do this just yesterday or maybe _anteayer_? Definition  of "call" the vote?

Comment: Am I included in that "we"?

Comment: Nope..I mean the community here who have been fielding questions about the elections, and the terminology. If you are feeling excluded, perhaps you need to research the Q ...

Comment: I asked it by the SO app, didn't get similar suggestions. You can tag it as repetitive one if it was asked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call)

> 11: to say or guess what the result will be
> *The election is too close to call.*

So it means that the AP predicted that Biden will win Arizona's vote for President.

Comment: I suspect the idiom arises from "calling" sports events.

Comment: @HotLicks Isn't it something to do with [calling in poker](https://upswingpoker.com/glossary/call/)? I don't play poker so I'm not sure.

Comment: @BoldBen - I don't play poker either, but my understanding is that "calling" has a different meaning there.

Comment: @BoldBen I don't think that meaning is at all related.

Comment: Rather, all these different meanings are eventually derived from the basic idea of announcing things.

Comment: But calling in poker just announces that you're matching the bet. It has little specific relationship to predicting a result.

Comment: Rather than poker, I'd say it's more closely associated with baseball or tennis, where the role of an umpire is to 'call' balls, strikes, lines etc. These are often "too close to call"

Comment: Related to calling a horse race. As in elections, the caller does not determine the winner, but merely announces it.

Comment: @JimMack Sounds about right, I know about as much about baseball as I do about poker but I do know that the line judges 'call' balls out.